# PageBlockTable not rendering the data

Tags: apex, rest-api, json, callout, pageblocktable

I have an apex callout that sends an sql query to an external MySQL server. The query output is returned in the response body and I could see that retrieved correctly in the console. But when the JSON string returned from the external server is de-serialized and coded to an a custom object list and added as a pageblocktable content, it is not getting rendered. I am not able to see any column values. The list data is correctly shown with values in console.

Can anyone please help me to find where the problem is?

**VF Code** - show_stores.vfp

```
<apex:page controller="query">
    <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Queries">
        <apex:commandButton value="View All Stores"  action="{!sendQuery}" reRender="table1" />
      </apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!result}" var="res">
            <apex:column value="{!res.storeNo}" headerValue="Store No"/>
            <apex:column value="{!res.storeName}" headerValue="Store Name"/>          
         </apex:pageBlockTable>    
       </apex:pageBlock>
     </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

***Controller*** - query.apxc

```
    public  String queryString{get;set;}
    public  List<myObj> result{get;set;}
    
    public pageReference sendQuery(){
        string s;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setMethod('GET');
        req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.example.com/endpointselect.php');
        query x = new query();
        x.queryString = 'Select * from test';
        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(x);
        system.debug('Sending string'+JSONString);
        req.setBody(JSONString);
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
        s=res.getBody();
        system.debug('Receiving string:'+s);
        List<myObj> result = (List<myObj>)JSON.deserialize(s, List<myObj>.class);
        system.debug(result);
       //return result;
        return null;
    }    
}
```

**myObj class** - myObj.apxc

```
global class myObj {
    public string storeNo{get;set;}
    public string storeName{get;set;}   
       
    public void insert1(){
        myObj x = new myObj();
        x.storeNo = this.StoreNo;
        x.StoreName = this.StoreName;
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://www.example.com/endpoint.php');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        String JSONString = JSON.serialize(x);
        system.debug(JSONString);
        req.setBody(JSONString);
        HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to iterate over a `List<myObj>` which wont work like that.

Try this, I have removed all the callouts and made an simple example:

```
public String queryString { get; set; }
public List<myObj> result { get; set; }
public List<Integer> indexes { get; set; }

public pageReference sendQuery() {
    string s;
    queryString = 'This is life';
    List<myObj> result = (List<myObj>) JSON.deserialize('[{"storeNo":"123","storeName":"TestName"}]', List<myObj>.class);
    this.result = result;
    this.indexes = new List<Integer>();
    for (Integer i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
        this.indexes.add(i);
    }
    system.debug(result);
    //return result;
    return null;
}

public class myObj {
    public string storeNo { get; set; }
    public string storeName { get; set; }
}
```

and you VFPage as :

```
<apex:page controller="DeleteAllBigObject">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Queries">
            <apex:commandButton value="View All Stores"  action="{!sendQuery}" reRender="table1">
            </apex:commandButton>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock id="table1">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Indexes}" var="i">
                <apex:column value="{!result[i].storeNo}" headerValue="Store No"/>
                <apex:column value="{!result[i].storeName}" headerValue="Store Name"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks Nagendra. It worked.